# Extracting numbers into a string array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a string which is of the form

```
String str = "124333 is the otp of candidate number 9912111242. 
         Please refer txn id 12323335465645 while referring blah blah.";
```

I need `124333`, `9912111242` and `12323335465645` in a string array. I have tried this with

```
while (Character.isDigit(sms.charAt(i)))
```

I feel that running the above said method on every character is inefficient. Is there a way I can get a string array of all the numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
String[] nbs = str.split("[^0-9]+");
```

This will split the `String` on any group of non-numbers digits.

Comment: @user1051505 `\D` is `[^0-9]` BTW, so `[^0-9]+` is simply `\D+` (and you need to escape the backslash so you end up with `\\D+`.

Answer (score 9):

Use a regex (see [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(<your string here>);
while (m.find()) {
    //m.group() contains the digits you want
}
```

you can easily build `ArrayList` that contains each matched group you find.

Or, as other suggested, you can split on non-digits characters (`\D`):

```
"blabla 123 blabla 345".split("\\D+")
```

Note that `\` has to be escaped in Java, hence the need of `\\`.

Answer (score 4):

And this works perfectly for your input.

```
String str = "124333 is the otp of candidate number 9912111242. Please refer txn id 12323335465645 while referring blah blah.";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("\\D+")));
```

Output:

```
[124333, 9912111242, 12323335465645]
```

`\\D+` Matches one or more non-digit characters. Splitting the input according to one or more non-digit characters will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Java 8 style:

```
long[] numbers = Pattern.compile("\\D+")
                        .splitAsStream(str)
                        .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
                        .toArray();
```

Ah if you only need a String array, then you can just use String.split as the other answers suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
String str = "124333 is the otp of candidate number 9912111242. Please refer txn id 12323335465645 while referring blah blah.";

str = str.replaceAll("\\D+", ",");
    
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
```

`\\D+` matches one or more non digits

#### Output

```
[124333, 9912111242, 12323335465645]
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing comes into my mind is filter and split, then i realized that it can be done via

`String[] result =str.split("\\D+");`

\D matches any non-digit character, + says that one or more of these are needed, and leading \ escapes the other \ since \D would be parsed as 'escape character D' which is invalid